# Issue restreaming with ffmpeg if source/destination drops

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using the following command to restream a video stream to another server, but if the source/destination momentarily drops, ffmpeg gives up.

```
ffmpeg \
-i http://source_stream_ip:port \
-reconnect_at_eof 1 \
-reconnect_streamed 1 \
-y \
-shortest \
-c: libx264 \
    -crf:v 22 \
    -preset:v fast \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -x264opts keyint=10:no-scenecut=1 \
    -maxrate:v 256k \
    -bufsize:v 512k \
-c:a aac \
    -ac 2 \
    -b:a 96k \
    -maxrate:a 96k \
    -bufsize:a 192k \
-f flv \
rtmp://destination_stream_ip:port
```

I've tried this as a batch command, but it also eventually gives up.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
ffmpeg \
-i http://source_stream_ip:port \
-reconnect_at_eof 1 \
-reconnect_streamed 1 \
-y \
-shortest \
-c: libx264 \
    -crf:v 22 \
    -preset:v fast \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -x264opts keyint=10:no-scenecut=1 \
    -maxrate:v 256k \
    -bufsize:v 512k \
-c:a aac \
    -ac 2 \
    -b:a 96k \
    -maxrate:a 96k \
    -bufsize:a 192k \
-f flv \
rtmp://destination_stream_ip:port
done
```

Could anyone recommend an improvement to doing this or even another way of doing this even without ffmpeg by using another command line tool? At the moment it is too unreliable to use on a permanent basis.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

```
 -reconnect_on_network_error 1 -reconnect_on_http_error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-reconnect_at_eof` and `-reconnect_streamed` options should be put before `-i SOURCE`:

```
ffmpeg \
-reconnect_at_eof 1 \
-reconnect_streamed 1 \
-i http://source_stream_ip:port \
...
```

Comment: Even doing it before -i I get `Option reconnect_at_eof not found`. Using the latest build `ffmpeg-git-20220910-amd64-static`.

Comment: @Mint Check where you're putting it in your command line... it definitely works.